# prcomp + ggbiplot : invalid 'rot' value

Tags: r

I am a real beginner in programming. I previously ran a PCA without normalizing my data and using

```
pca1 <- prcomp(df1[, -1792],  scale = TRUE)
```

where column 1792 was a non-numeric value (stages of a disease).I also filtered in this case with my 1791 "golden" DEGs (Differentially Expressed Genes).
I then ran this ggbiplot code with no issue:

```
ggbiplot(pca1, groups=factor (df1$stage), alpha=1, varname.size=0.2, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE, labels =row.names(df1)) +theme_bw()
```

but I have a very low PC1+PC2 contribution (variance explained: ~34%).

I'm now trying to run a PCA after I have used the DESeq2 function

```
df2 <- vst(dds, blind = FALSE)
```

to normalize my data. dds comes from a function within deseq2 but what matters is that when I use

```
df2 <- assay(df2)
```

I get a dataframe with normalized counts so then I can use the scale=F in the prcomp:

```
pca2 <- prcomp(df2, scale=FALSE)
```

The pca runs properly but once I run the ggbiplot I get this error

```
plot <- ggbiplot(pca2, groups=factor (df2$stage), alpha=1, varname.size=0.2, ellipse = TRUE, circle = TRUE, labels =row.names(df2))
> plot
Error in validDetails.text(x) : invalid 'rot' value
```

The df2 has 62 rows and 18041 coumns. The column names are the genes, not filtered with the "golden" 1791 DEGs.

Does anyone know what this issue could be?

```
 dput(vstFnaflf2[1:2])
structure(list(ENSG00000000003 = c(11.4215544074842, 11.3369519651205, 
11.5448391216299, 11.2668610511339, 10.8654320557767, 11.4886601274776, 
11.1553462673246, 10.8894337958264, 11.3799538821303, 11.1834947682376, 
11.1377551871347, 10.8635788490664, 10.7571820846599, 11.2293442248949, 
11.242436020635, 11.1190373991806, 11.4220714063675, 11.3441908169498, 
11.1158875256387, 11.4749364557432, 11.2191249607138, 10.680739153785, 
11.029716588235, 10.4306314563696, 11.1063383712873, 10.6729270823035, 
10.7778905669614, 10.4691752830184, 10.9689082384651, 11.2816279203297, 
11.0424792087751, 11.6996231284794, 11.1902799982159, 10.8527510875352, 
11.3022219384651, 11.1458750833418, 10.8359910845809, 11.2148430328843, 
10.9732261450675, 10.2091729321716, 11.1967880011015, 10.9659701944552, 
10.838617541679, 11.1004203325252, 10.6932651834237, 10.5629477735197, 
10.2605983436435, 10.4749930961273, 10.4742010629573, 9.76884707077027, 
10.3490782724558, 10.0733457365331, 9.92868836741446, 10.5738569015904, 
11.2038970989381, 11.2849826368472, 11.0610922087208, 10.4281519728595, 
10.6111525987206, 11.4163114688057, 11.2237933238777, 11.3615193043112
), ENSG00000000005 = c(4.76699423435736, 4.68240208192305, 3.83645876209821, 
3.83645876209821, 4.66839871345985, 4.79885068975568, 4.416012172989, 
3.83645876209821, 5.36435617001811, 4.26063011770966, 4.53405567978961, 
4.33533017372147, 3.83645876209821, 4.33383458328636, 3.83645876209821, 
3.83645876209821, 4.59610823121884, 4.17207999667687, 3.83645876209821, 
5.32000950445877, 4.39196210894947, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 
4.21330292986232, 4.31404327784339, 4.2226205020253, 3.83645876209821, 
3.83645876209821, 4.25346930315269, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 
3.83645876209821, 5.706574065477, 4.49155709713843, 4.7605669687025, 
4.81682091160677, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 5.23038711339047, 
4.9317232361801, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 4.63880384026439, 
3.83645876209821, 5.0817203747019, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 
3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 4.50626310563055, 
4.41409771719511, 4.26279976373479, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 
4.2035349073738, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 3.83645876209821, 
4.35675165408212, 3.83645876209821, 4.17523694633528)), row.names = c("control001", 
"control002", "control003", "control004", "control005", "control006", 
"control007", "control008", "control009", "control010", "patient007", 
"patient009", "patient011", "patient012", "patient019", "patient026", 
"patient028", "patient029", "patient044", "patient056", "patient058", 
"patient059", "patient070", "patient073", "patient081", "patient085", 
"patient086", "patient089", "patient092", "patient097", "patient101", 
"patient107", "patient109", "patient110", "patient113", "patient114", 
"patient116", "patient118", "patient120", "patient121", "patient123", 
"patient129", "patient131", "patient132", "patient137", "patient139", 
"patient143", "patient144", "patient146", "patient151", "patient152", 
"patient156", "patient158", "patient164", "patient166", "patient178", 
"patient184", "patient187", "patient188", "patient199", "patient201", 
"patient206"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: I struggle to understand your code because `pca` is used twice in same function but we don't know how it was generated. I suppose you would mean `pca = prcomp...` but in the second case, it is still unclear if `df` is the same as the previous `df`. Please enlight us on these points, it is also unclear for `dds`

Comment: So i modified this a little bit to make it more clear. Like i mentioned the dds comes from the deseq2 vignette but when using the assay it gives me a df that i can use to run the prcomp. The code is longer that this of course i just mentioned key-point to see if anyone has encountered this error before and what they did to fix it.

Comment: so df2 is "a dataframe with normalized counts" but you invoke df2$stage in the prcomp function, I think there is something wrong here

Comment: Even when i use a simple ggbiplot(pca2) i still get the same error. Using biplot(pca2) doesnt give me that error but i cant make sense of the results.

Comment: Could you provide an example of your data.frame `df2` with `dput(df2[,1:20])` ?

Comment: @Basti I provided the info in the question since it was too big to add as a comment. I only did [1:2] because the data is too big but it should give a fair example of what is going on.

Comment: Thank you, however I have no error and `ggbiplot(pca2)` works well with the example you provided

Comment: @Basti Is it possible then that the number of columns i provide are too big? I have 18401 columns (or genes) with 62 rows. Or could it be that there are some values within that could interfere? Like 0 some rowsums where it is 0?

Comment: @Basti apparently there were some values that i had to remove with vstFnaflf2[,apply(vstFnaflf2, 2, var, na.rm=TRUE) != 0]
For some reason i saw this post back when i tried to run the pca but it wouldnt apply on my df. I rerun the whole df making process and run that and it remove ~500 values and then the prcomp ran properly! Sorry to bother you and thanks for the help!